# How to return formatted dates in mongorepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm thinking here is it possible to return a date converted into an @Aggregation annotation. I tried to use $dateFromString but without success if someone can help me I appreciate it.

obs: format I want the date dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss

follow my code:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
    "{ '$match': { 'userid' : ?0} }", 
    "{ '$sort': {_id: -1}}",
    "{ '$skip' : ?1 }", 
    "{ '$limit' : ?2 }"
  })
List<CartPurchaseMongo> findPurchase(
    Long userId,
    int skip,
    int limit
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to return a date converted into an @Aggregation annotation using $dateFromString in the pipeline.

```html
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
    "{ '$match': { 'userid' : ?0} }", 
    "{ '$sort': {_id: -1}}",
    "{ '$skip' : ?1 }", 
    "{ '$limit' : ?2 }",
    "{ '$addFields': { 'purchaseDate': { '$dateFromString': { 'dateString': '$purchaseDate', 'format': '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' } } } }"
})
List<CartPurchaseMongo> findPurchase(
    Long userId,
    int skip,
    int limit
);
```

You'll need to replace the 'purchaseDate' field in the $dateFromString stage with the name of the field in your CartPurchaseMongo class that contains the date string to convert.

Comment: My field is of type date is there any way to convert it to the format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' my command to insert date is: `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())`